# what techniques do react websites use to update static data?

Tags: reactjs

I have a web developer using React to develop a Point-Of-Sale website. The website is mostly front end. I developed an API that the website uses to pull and post data to my desktop app's database. So basically the API delivers a menu specific to the user, the website allows the user to ring up a sale and the website posts the sale by passing the shopping cart to the API. So that the user specific menu is smaller (meaning less data and/or network traffic), the website needs to pull a master menu with product descriptions, etc from the API once daily (maybe 1AM when few users on the website), then only the things like SKU and price (user specific) are sent when the user logs in. The API is called to get this user's specific menu. How do websites update things like my master menu periodically (daily, hourly or only when an update is available)? I believe we have decided on Redux to store data locally.

The website calls the API once a day to pull the master menu. The master menu contains sku and item description (about 30 characters) for about 1000 items. That data is stored locally. I did that so that when a user logs in and the website calls the API to get a custom menu for the user, I do not send the item description thereby reducing the amount of data. Because the user specific menu only contains the sku, the website gets the corresponding item description from the master menu. Theoretically that makes sense to an old desktop app developer because we are simply passing less data over the network. My question is, assuming I do things this way, how does the website periodically update the master menu or how do I let the website know that a master menu update is available and should be applied.

Comment: _"I believe we have decided on Redux to store data locally"_ - Redux is not a database. It is a design-pattern and/or the name of its main implementation in JS. Your data will not be persisted at all and will disappear whenever the browser tab is closed.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking.  Wouldn't the data which drives this "menu" simply be fetched by an API call (via AJAX)?  If for performance reasons the server needs to retain a local copy of the data and not repeatedly query some other back-end system, that's not really a concern of the front-end.

Comment: You could pull a master list and store it in IndexDB.  This can be used as a "cache" for your master list.  Keep a meta record in the DB noting the last hash or last updated or version of the master list.  You can check every time you open the app or keep track of when you last checked.  No matter what, as with all things client-side, you ***MUST*** verify anything that you submit against the server whenever you use this data.  You can't let the client-side DB dictate the price of things and such.

Comment: Remember I am a desktop developer so I am not understanding what you mean by "You can check every time you open the app or keep track of when you last checked.". What does "open the app" mean? Thanks for your patience

Comment: Just an FYI that seeking recommendations and advice are considered off-topic and likely won't be well received. Try to [edit] the post to focus on a more specific topic or issue. See [Help/How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

Answer (score 0):

For the data fetching part, I recommend using [tanstack query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest), a library that supports reloading data periodically or at will. Some features that it supports are:

- retrieving data after some time has passed
- retrieving data after the user focus your tab
- manually marking a query as invalid to fetch it again immediately
- detecting network changes and reloading data after the wifi connection has been lost and then regained

There are some details that make different a web page from a desktop app that you may want to acknowledge:

- you cannot have a background service to fetch data (well [you can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), but it is not preferable for most websites). This means that every data retrieval must be done while the page is open in the client
- you cannot write to persistent files. However you can use localStorage to store any persistent data you need (but safari will erase it if the user doesn't access your page during 7 days)
- related with the previous, anyways the best for websites usually is to keep data in-memory, and that is where libraries like Redux are introduced. Redux data will be erased after closing the browser tab, but you should fetch it again after loading again the page

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your website is storing in the local storage of the client browser a cache with the data about menus, you want to be able to update this data either periodically or even better when the master data have been updated.

There is various options, IMO the best would be Server Sent Events.

**Server Sent Events**

To trigger an update of your cache data on all browsers of your customers, Server Sent Events could be a solution, the limitation is that the communication is only `server >> client`. [See documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

**Scheduled task in browser**

As proposed in @Feder 240516 answer, Tanstack seems interesting for it's periodical reload

**Long polling & HTTP Cache**

Your browser code could periodically call your API and if the data didn't changed the API would answer with the HTTP code 304 "Not Modified", which would stop the process here. Until data is updated on the server and then your API will serve the fresh data to the browser on the next periodical call [See documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304)

**Websockets**

If you expects to add features to your website that will require bi-directional communication `server <> client`, then websockets could be of interest. [See documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: I can easily see that I am way over my head on this subject. Olaurendeau, when you said "To trigger an update of your cache data on all browsers of your customers", that is totally overwhelming to my feeble brain. I am going to pass this thread to my developer and let him weed through all this very good knowledge. Thank you all